# Count previous day

Tags: count, powerbi, dax

I trying to build a measure that will count the number of work types from the day before and have the below Dax Measure.

```
PD Count = CALCULATE(SUM('BANCS Daily'[Wkr_Type]),PREVIOUSDAY('BANCS Daily'[DATE]))
```

The Dax returns no errors, but when I try to attach to a visual, I am presented with the below error.
[image]

Any help on this or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try counting instead of summing(which only works with number data types)

```
PD Count = CALCULATE(COUNT('BANCS Daily'[Wkr_Type]),PREVIOUSDAY('BANCS Daily'[DATE]))
```